# Writing file from base64 data in an ASPX page with C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, base64

I'm trying to take the base64 encrypted version of a file, decrypt it, and write the file to the server. I can't figure out why this code isn't working, and any help would be appreciated, as of right now I'm getting the error: `File Not Found`. Here's my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
    //string data = Decode(c.Request["file"]);
    //string name = c.Request["name"];
    string name = "target.docx";
    string data = Decode("SUPER LONG BASE 64, DIDNT POST BECAUSE WAY TOO LARGE");
    StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("~/services/temp/"+name));
    // Error generated here, after previous line.
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    writer.Close();
    Response.Redirect("temp/"+name);
  }
  public string Decode(string str){
    byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decbuff);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it actually creating the file, but not redirecting to it? Or is it not even creating the file?

Comment: What is thr throw there ? check here the throws of the File.CreateText http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

Comment: @icemanind, it's not even creating the file.  
@Aristos, I'll check that out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to make a local directory off of the wwwroot since the directories created in sharepoint designer weren't physical, here is the code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
    //string data = Decode(c.Request["file"]);
    //string name = c.Request["name"];
    Response.Write(Server.MapPath("/temp/hurrdurr.txt"));
    string name = "target.docx";
    string data = "THE GIANT BASE 64 DATA";
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("/temp/"+name), true)){
      writer.WriteLine(Decode(data));
      writer.Close();
    }
    FileStream fs = File.Open(Server.MapPath("/temp/"+name), FileMode.Open);
    byte[] file = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(file, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    fs.Close();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(file);
    Response.End();
  }
  public string Decode(string str){
    byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decbuff);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the temporary file entirely.

```
string sName = "target.docx";
string sBase64 = "THE GIANT BASE 64 DATA";        
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sName);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Convert.FromBase64String(sBase64));
Response.End();
```